# Change relative path of programs in %PATH% variable to absolute path

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, path, which

Inside `cmd.exe` when I call `which java` I get this output:

> /c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java

When I call `which vagrant` I get:

> /c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java

But when I call `which ssh` I get:

> /usr/bin/ssh

I fear that this relative path causes a problem somewhere else.

Why does `ssh` return a relative path? How can I make `ssh` reference an absolute path?

Comment: "How can I make ssh reference an absolute path?" - Edit your PATH variable to include a more complete path to the executable.  How you edit the PATH variable is well documented.  There are many answers that explain how you edit it here at Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path is actually complete. You're not using (pure) `cmd.exe`. There is no SSH under Windows so you're probably using Cygwin or similar as there is no `which` command on Windows either. As you can already see by the output from those other commands the paths also start with `/` as `/` references the root of a Linux filesystem.

Comment: Yes. I was using `which` from my Git installation. The commands with the relative paths were also part of my Git installation.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown - Just so you're clear: _all_ of the paths you cite are absolute, as is any path beginning with `/`; relative paths begin with `./`, `../`, or any other directory name without a leading `/`. A file name with no directory is always relative. Note that I am talking about your local file system: remote systems can be addressed with prefixes such as `net://`, though not all Windows versions of Unix utilities support this.